# Something wierd with NHProfiler

Tags: nhprof

Hello i was using nhprofiler and it was working fine now it dont wanna even start i click on it to start get timecapsule then nothing happens any idea what can be wrong? Maybe someone has same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the build number that you're using?
What is the exception / StackTrace?
You can open an issue in the NHProf group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/nhprof

Comment: Build is latest NHibernate.Profiler-Build-930 there is no exception just nothing happens

Comment: Did you call `NHiberanteProfiler.Initialize()` at the first thing in your application?